# Верстка email писем 2к18/19

Tags: html, css, email, вёрстка-email

Уже несколько лет не верстал email-писем, изменилось ли что-нибудь? Мы по прежнему верстаем на таблицах, а стили – инлайним? Я пытался найти статистики использования почтовых клиентов, чтобы проверить поддержку CSS-свойств на [caniuse.email](https://caniuse.email), но все они оказались без указания версий почтовых клиентов: [litmus.com](https://litmus.com/blog/email-client-market-share-trends-first-half-of-2018), [emailmonday.com](https://www.emailmonday.com/mobile-email-usage-statistics/).

> Сообщения могут открывать в почтовых клиентах и браузерах, которые не
>   поддерживают новые версии HTML и CSS. Табличная верстка – залог того,
>   что письмо не «разъедется» и нормально отобразится на всех платформах.
>   – [Источник](https://www.unisender.com/ru/blog/sovety/kak-sverstat-pismo-instruktsiya-dlya-chaynikov)

Ситуация такая же, как и с CSS Grid Layout – складывается ощущение, что до последнего момента мы откладываем новые технологии, чтобы поддерживать почти мёртвые браузеры или старые почтовые клиенты, как в нашем случае. Поделитесь статистиками, если у вас таковые имеются, может только у меня сложилось впечатление, что целевая аудитория сверстанных писем уже давно сидит на Gmail и Mail App, и можно разгуляться с использованием HTML5 тегов, медиа запросов и прочих «плюшек».

Если не разводить дискуссию и допустить, что всё по-прежнему печально и вёрстка писем – это таблицы с инлайн стилями, то какие инструменты сейчас используются? В ходу ли фреймворки, например [Zurb Foundation for Emails 2](https://foundation.zurb.com/emails.html) – это единственное, что нашел я с поддержкой препроцессоров. Или своя сборка с [inline-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inline-css) и вперёд?

В Google прошу не слать – все статьи или устарели или переформулируют одни и те же идеи из года в год без какого-либо авторитетного мнения.

Comment: Юзал MJML - полет нормальный. https://mjml.io. Ну, так все да всё плохо - всё покрыто паутиной и плесенью из-за oulook'a например.

Comment: Коллега, на [этой проверке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/329866) правильно было подать тревогу "не является ответом" (это ответ-ссылка). Пожалуйста, будьте внимательнее в очереди проверок и не торопитесь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

За последние несколько лет основные почтовые клиенты нисколько не поменялись. Всё так же, всё те же Outlook и прочие старые и древние присутствуют. Значит всё также инлайним стили если нужно чтобы письма открывались везде.

Сайты из гугла всё делают правильно, по большому счёту ничего не поменялось. Да, какой-то CSS теперь можно указывать внутри `<style>` [для, например, Gmail начиная с 2016 года](https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/css), и [для некоторых других клиентов тоже](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/style-element/style-in-head/), но для всех остальных всё так же как и раньше. Значит верстаем как обычно.

Из относительно нового можно отметить программы, которые автоматом инлайнят стили прямо в теги (пример [раз](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inline-css), [два](https://github.com/Automattic/juice)). Впрочем, несколько лет назад они тоже были.

Answer (score 3):

В глобальном плане всё по-прежнему печально и верстка писем – это таблицы с инлайн стилями. Но в 2018 году советую использовать эмейл-фреймворк [MJML](https://mjml.io/try-it-live).

**Плюсы:**

- бесплатно;
- простой в изучении и в работе;
- не конструктор, а фреймворк;
- можно работать прямо в браузере.

**Минусы:**

- нужно учить новый синтаксис.

Answer (score 2):

Да, всё верно ничего не поменялось. Всё также верстаем таблицами. Но только теперь появились сервисы-конструкторы для быстрой вёрстки писем - у самих сервисов e-mail-рассылки и на сторонних ресурсах, например вот этот - https://stripo.email/ru/ .

С открытым доступом к коду, и возможностью скачивания и редактирования html-документа.

По фреймворкам честно сказать не знаю. Не встречал. На данный момент актуальные почтовые сервисы - gmail и yandex. И если использовать конструктор, а потом приводить всё в чувство, то вполне адаптивно и работает.